# Checking contents of char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following structure and have some code to use it below. The control is not going into the `if` statement(I need to check if the `chat_info[queue].message` is empty which it is)

```
struct chat{
    char message[MAXNAME];
    int client;
    int group;
    int flag;
};
.
.
.
.

if(filedata.data==NULL)
        {
        printf("\n  data is %s",filedata.data);} //displays "data is "
        chat_info[queue].message[0]='\0'; //setting 0 before copying data
        strcpy(chat_info[queue].message,filedata.data);
        printf("\n  data is %s",chat_info[queue].message);//displays "data is "
        if(chat_info[queue].message[0]=='\0'){
   // not going into this if statement
   //I also tried if(chat_info[queue].message== "") and if(chat_info[queue].message== NULL)
}
```

Comment: `if(filedata.data==NULL);` --> drop the trailing `;`  Suggest using an auto formatter to help see the issues.

Comment: Why the need to null terminate the message when you overwrite the contents right afterwards?

Comment: That semicolon was a typo sorry- I still have the problem

Comment: Please don't correct errors like that. People need to follow the comments.

Comment: same problem even if i remove chat_info[queue].message[0]='\0';

Comment: `message` can contain whitespace so it looks like empty, but is not. Try adding quotes around

Comment: I can't see why you don't get a segfault (or a polite "(null)" inserted by `printf`) in `if(filedata.data == NULL) { printf("\n  data is %s", filedata.data); }`

Comment: @Vasfed I tried that it displays ** (for *%s*)

Comment: @weather Vane-  I donno why it does that- no segfault

Comment: Well the whole thing seems to be a muddle, lack of proper indentation and incomplete code block do not help.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for your help regarding bad indendation , correction of typos and muddled code- this is a part of a much larger code and doesn't make sense posting the whole thing. I got a reply below which actually helped..

Comment: @noob you are welcome, but I did point out the error repeated in the fuller answer. You are asked to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried, then we don't have any nonsense about typos and incomplete code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see:

```
if (filedata.data == NULL)
```

Which can also be written as:

```
if (!filedata.data)
```

Once inside the if-statement you attempt to copy the contents of `filedata.data` into `chat_info[queue].message`. However, we previously established that `filedata.data` points to nothing. It is NULL. Using `strcpy()` with a NULL pointer as the source should not work.

Perhaps you meant:

```
if (filedata.data != NULL)
```

Which can also be written as:

```
if (filedata.data)
```

Secondly, if `filedata.data` wasn't NULL, think about when `chat_info[queue].message[0] == '\0'` would be true.

```
strcpy(chat_info[queue].message, filedata.data);
if(chat_info[queue].message[0] == '\0') {
   // Message was determined to be empty.
}
```

It would only be true if the `filedata.data` was an empty string. **(Note: this is different than being NULL!)** Is that what you want? If so, the current code should work fine.

Reference: [strcpy() documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is the type for `message`? Because, if it is a string, then it will implicitly cast when you set it to a char `= '\0';`. Perhaps, you need to do:

`if (chat_info[queue].message[0] == "\0")`

Comment: character array -   char message[MAXNAME];

Comment: Okay - so that rules out my original suggestion. Here is an observation:

Your first `if` statement only executes if the `file.data` is `null`. So why are you calling `strcpy` for the file.data, which we know is null? I have a feeling something weird is happening here. Have you tried:

`if (chat_info[queue].message[0] == NULL`

Comment: if you can see that the if statement was just to print out filedata and check its contents(closing bracket of if statement at the end)

Comment: Okay - I see that now. As an aside, you should always make blocks distinguishable.

Anyway - `chat_info[queue].message` is not necessarily `'\0'` after you use `strcpy`, since you are copying `file.data` into `chat_info[queue].message`. You need to figure out what file.data is if you want to determine what `chat_info[queue].message[0]` is going to be. As it is now, you are essentially doing nothing with the line: `chat_info[queue].message[0] = '\0'`

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(chat_info[queue].message,filedata.data);
/* You have assigned some data for chat_info[queue].message
 * in the above step assignment should be successful.
 */

if(chat_info[queue].message[0]=='\0')
/* How can message[0] be null? It will never be. Think of what you're
 * trying to achieve with the condition.
 * If you're checking for a non-empty message, then it should be
 * chat_info[queue].message[0]!='\0'
 */
{
./* some stuff here */
}
```